# Кольцевые ссылки в Spring

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте.

У меня такая ситуация: в контексте определено 3 бина. 2 из них представляют собой классы моего приложения (оба `Runnable`), а 3 - `ArrayList`. В первых 2 бинах есть ссылка на этот бин-`ArrayList`. Я хочу в 1 бине добавлять компоненты в этот `ArrayList`, ждать завершения добавления, после чего поднимать 2-ой бин и использовать значения из этого `ArrayList`. Будет ли такая конструкция работать, правильно ли вообще так делать?

```
<bean name="firstbean" class="com.fistbean">
    <property name="list" ref="mainlist" />
</bean>

<bean name="secondbean" class="com.secondbean">
    <property name="list" ref="mainlist" />
</bean>

<bean name="mainlist" class="java.util.ArrayList">
</bean>
```

После этого я делаю так:

```
FirstBean f = ObjectFactory.getObject("firstbean");
f.start() // Тут происходит добавления в ArrayList
f.join();
SecondBean s = ObjectFactory.getObject("secondbean");
s.start();// Тут из этого ArrayList читаются значения
```

Как-то так :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не очень понятно описали, извините. Что значит "поднимать бин" - они у вас не по дефолту (синглетоны) что ли? Если нет и вы хотите ссылаться из бинов друг на друга то вам возможно потребуется сделать ссылку "proxy". В общем, лучше бы контекст запостили. А в принципе работать "кольцевая ссылка" сама по себе будет без проблем... %)

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Со ссылками проблем вроде не будет.

А вам нужно, чтобы оба бина представляли потоки, в которых асинхронные действия происходят? Что-то мне кажется, что в этом случае вам эти бины с помощью бина-Екзекутора какого-нибудь надо запускать (вы не написали, откуда вы их стартуете, но осмелюсь предположить, что это в любом случае будет не то, чего вы хотели). А что вы хотите? Если вы их от `Thread` унаследуете, то может и вызовется (но ведь это будет однократно выполняемый бин т.к. синглетон), да и по-моему, свои треды запускать нехорошо. А если просто от `Runnable`, то и выполняться вроде не должно

Comment: вот что я имею в виду: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

Comment: имлименчу Runnable и создаю тред отсдельно, просто для экономии места не описал этого в коде примера. Посмотрю ссылку, спасибо

Comment: Если тред руками создаёте - то не надо так делать. Не все (или почти никакие) серверы приложений с этим будут правильно работать (если я вас правильно понял) - сам на это наткнулся когда-то. Тогда со ссылкой точно надо разбираться. %)

(хотя по-моему если тред создать в сервлете который сам дожидается пока порождённые треды закончат работу - тогда можно)

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли что это вебапп ? ))